# How can i download internet image from a URL using paperclip gem in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails,I want to download image from internet through url.

i refer this tutorial [link](https://mensfeld.pl/2013/12/rails-paperclip-open-uri-downloading-files-from-the-internet-and-saving-them-with-paperclip/)  but i am confused, where i want add this code in controller or model or in view.
pls help me where i add code or better way.

Comment: What do you mean by "download an image from a URL"? Do you mean that want the user to be able to download the image from your rails app or that you want your server to download an image from the internet and store it with paperclip? The tutorial you have linked is about the later.

Comment: Download from internet.

Comment: Its still not very clear how and where you want this to happen. If you can write a general outline in terms of "When the user does X I expect Y to happen" that will help us give you answers that are actually relevant.

Comment: i want to download image from internet,
part 1 =i do upload image form computer and save to image table  it work properly,
part 2 =now i want to download image form internet using same image model or using new model.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<%= link_to "Download", page.item_image.url(:original, false) %>
```

Comment: What does the second arg do here? The [docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip%2FAttachment:url) show this as being for an options hash?